# Wireless Audio transmission (single TX -> single RX): Clock synchronisation/recovery

Tags: audio, wireless, audio-codec

I am searching for a way to stream an audio signal to a single speaker in the living room. (I do NOT need brodcast to multiple receivers / multiroom)

Audio quality is a major concern, since the preamp / amp and speaker are rather good quality and I don´t want to feed them lousy audio data.

To be specific, I plan something like:
NAS(using e.g. Icecast, codec + hardware unclear) -> Bluetooth or WLAN -> Wireless Receiver -> Codec -> Audio Amplifier.

My question is how do I choose the components involved in the wireless transmitting path up to the codec so that I get high quality audio without "Noise" and clicking because of clock deviations between the transmitting side (the NAS server clock) and the receiver codec clock? In other words what hard/software components can I use to synchronise the PC/NAS side codec with the receiving codec? Is there a WLAN/BT protocol which has such a feature built in?

(I assume since I only have on receiver, I could jsut playback the data as I receive it from the sender and the sender takes care of the proper playback rate. But I guess that would result in a huge amount of jitter/audio distortion because of latencies in the wireless channel?)

Comment: I'd use a cable. Justify why you can't.

Comment: Well, the speaker is not near the NAS and I don´t want to pull wires through 3 rooms... also I think the task should be achievable with at least manageable effort in year 2020 =)
I think BLE Audio is coming up, but it will take some more time, also don´t know If there is synchronisation. Bluetooth Classic has a crappy codec as far as I understood

Comment: Raspberry Pi + DAC board in the room - it'll buffer data locally, and provide the clock. Have a search for MPD systems, lots of examples. Don't try and synchronise clocks in the way you're describing, it won't work!

Comment: @awjlogan: I already had a RPI up and running with Icecast some years ago but ther is still the problem that: The DAC was interfaced to RPI via I2S, and the I2S clock is locally derived. If the I2S clock is not synchronised to the sender, the drift will become bigger and bigger. i don´t see how buffering will improve the problem.
If the sender sends the data let´s say a bit too fast, buffers will overflow, if it sends too slow, the DAC has no input data....

Comment: @Junius The clock is not related to the sender, as the transmission is not real time. The RPi pulls in X amount of data ahead of being output, and then derives the clock used locally. The sender sends a stream, that is then decoded locally - the RPi generates the appropriate clock for the DAC. The RPi's I2S clock is not a normal sampling multiple, but you can slave it against a local reference.

Comment: See [Digital audio clock recovery from UDP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/107500/11683)

Comment: @awjlogan: Ah, I see. Was a mistake in my thinking. So the stream just has to be fast enough. But still, how does the sender know that the streaming rate is fast enough and how is it adapted bewtween server/receiver? That is handled by the protocol between NAS/Server and the RPI in this case, right? Does "every" typical streaming protocol take care of this internally?

Comment: @Junius It's all handled in whatever the transfer protocol is - the receiver sends a request, and the server returns the data. The receiver will buffer _some amount_ of data so it can handle breaks in transmission, but the actual decoding is done at the receiver.